# Menu not working for semantic UI like Example Code

Tags: semantic-ui

I am a beginner at web development and I am now using semantic-ui framework for my font-end development.I have tried the sample code for the first example menu at this link.

http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html

But my menu don't change active state on click like this.I have tried $("..").menu() method and it shows $(..).menu is not a function.I wonder if you could help me please.Shall I have to write my custom Javascript code to change active state on click or on hover.
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>


    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Semantic-UI-master/dist/semantic.min.css">


<script src="Semantic-UI-master/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<style>

    </style>
</head>
<div class="ui three item menu">
  <a class="item">Editorials</a>
  <a class="item">Reviews</a>
  <a class="item active">Upcoming Events</a>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.ui .item').on('click', function() {
   $('.ui .item').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. Can you please elaborate why this happens?

Comment: This is weird. When Semantic ships it's `js` and `css` shouldn't all the functionalities work out of the box?

Comment: That would make sense...in some aspect. But what if you have 2 or 10 menues on your page? Then you would have to separate them with different classes. So to make the framework work for all users, Sematic would need the user to setup what menu you are targeting when pressing that menu-button.

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly answering the initial question, I think it's worth pointing out that any dropdown-style menu will depend on the dropdown javascript. So for example, the following menu:

```
<div class="ui top attached menu">
  <div class="ui dropdown icon item">
    <i class="wrench icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">
        item text here...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Will need to be accompanied by:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just put `simple` in the menu class:
`<div class="ui simple three item menu">`